# Disabled option is not displaying with configurable attributes in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.0

We have setup the configurable products but when a product become out of stock, Still user are able to select that product. But every time, They receive the following message.
You need to choose options for your item.

Can we add disabled option with this attributes from admin panel so that user can not choose this option. (Already enabled "Display Out of Stock Products" )